# Resolving seondary dependencies of imported ES6 module in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, webpack, google-chrome-extension, node-modules, jspdf

I am building a Chrome extension which requires a third-party package, [JsPDF](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF). JsPDF has support for UMD, Node, and ES6. I have set up my Chrome extension to work as an ES6 module. I tried importing JsPDF like below.

```
import { jsPDF } from './../lib/jspdf.es.min.js'
```

I used the webpack-generated minified file, but JsPDF is also importing Babel and Fflate, which will be required to be imported separately. How should I resolve these dependencies?